# how can I delete the command history in swi-prolog

Tags: command-line, prolog, history, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

So, I enjoy the option of using the up and down arrow keys to search through the command history in Swi-Prolog instead of retyping commands. I want to know how I can delete the command history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history is per-directory kept in `~/.swipl-dir-history`.  The files there are base32 encoded directory names.  So, stop Prolog, find the right file, delete it and restart Prolog.